# Updating one table by selecting another table with identical structure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Well I m pretty stuck in this problem, I have two tables with identical structure, I want to update first table with values of 2nd table. I have following query but mysql is throwing the error.

```
UPDATE property p 
SET ROW = (SELECT * FROM temp_property t WHERE p.id= t.id)
```

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't update an entire row all at once.  You need to specify the column names.

```
UPDATE property p, temp_property t 
SET p.col1 = t.col1, etc 
WHERE p.id=tp.id
```

(Fixed query for MySQL.)